# Create Online Mall or Engine for create them

Tags: e-commerce

Does anyone know how to create an online mall? So, people can register at my website to create their self online shop, I as admin can approve the user and their items. But, I have a main web that contain another seller item (just like an ads or newest product), and people could see their store. Is there any engine/script to create that? I've google it and found X-Cart, but it so expensive, maybe anyone know another engine that free or cheaper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found : X-Cart, Opencart with Some module